# How do I show a custom dialog when there is no Internet connection?

Tags: android, android-layout, network-connection

I want to show a custom dialog in a webview app when there is no connection to the Internet. How can I check the Internet connection and after that call a dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check if there is an internet connection, and you can show a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) message to the user.

See also: [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

**Edit:**
Here is an example of how to do this with a Toast message:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info != null) {
    if (!info.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your wireless connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your wireless connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example how to do this?

Comment: When I try that example my app works fine if I have internet connection but if there is not connection I get force close?

Comment: Sorry. I should have added another check to be sure that `info` is not `null`. See my revised code.

Answer (score 0):

As Phil mentioned, the ConnectivityManager is the way to detect the internet connection on n Android app. However, if you don't want to use that and instead you want to have your app entirely in HTML, you could always show a locally available HTML page on your application. This local HTML could try to check if there is a connection to your server, and, if so, direct the user to your online page. If there is no connection, the local HTML page can show useful offline data, or just a message saying "Sorry, no internet connection."